# Android app to log a picture+description, and easily scroll them afterwards

Tags: gratis, android, photography, metadata, asset-management

Joe gives me a scarf, Jack gives me a book.
A month later, I don't remember who gave what.

I am looking for an Android app to keep track of that.

1. I take a picture,
2. I send it to the app,
3. I choose category `received-gift`
4. I write a description `from Joe, for birthday`.
5. I can see easily see all pictures+descriptions in that category, sorted by picture date.

Requirements:

- Runs on Android.
- Free.
- Open source (or at least the data must be easy to export, no vendor lock-in).
- Pictures are not mixed in a folder where other pictures are.

The less other features the better. An app that just allows me to very quickly rename the image file and move it to a special folder (and a subfolder for the category) would be the best.

Other tags could be `received-presents`, `given-presents`, `borrowed-items`, `tasted-wines`, etc. Bonus if data can be synchronized to Linux (ideally just by copying a folder).

Right now I am using Asset Manager Free, it does not allow to view all items in a category, and adding an item is cumbersome because there are too many other options.

Comment: Not tried any of them, but a [simple search for "lent"](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=lent) turns up some potential candidates. [Stuff Loans Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.valenji.prestamos) sounds like a close match. Or [Lend It!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.bitstreamtech.lendit).

Comment: @Izzy: I added a "category" requirements to make the question less broad, sorry. I tried your suggestion, data is locked-in.

Comment: Thanks, Nicolas! My suggestions were just "quick shots", so sorry they weren't "good matches". But wait, reading it again I remember an app I've used (even bought the pro) in the past which might offer that as a side-effect: Could you please take a look at [Note Everything](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.softxperience.android.noteeverything)? Not open-source, but you can easily export your data to SD card (and get a folder structure with text and media files in them).

Comment: Note Everything looks nice but does not seem to fulfill the 5th requirements. The list view shows only descriptions, not thumbnails of the pictures.

Comment: Yuck. I knew I must have missed something. Will be hard to find a full match I'm afraid. Good luck!